# After running a html code,my page doest not start from the first line as per the HTML code

Tags: html

After running a html code,I see that some part of next page content is seen in previous page and some times the page which has to start with some text and then followed by image ,I see page directly starts from image and I need to manually scroll up to see the text

I am using a nav bar which has 5 options and is fixed on the top.When I select the first option which is "about", I see that in my HTML it should start with a text which is h2,italic.But my "about" page is starting from image which is actiually my second line in my HTML .

Is that the image causing me this problem? If yes please help me out to find the solution

```css
.jumbotron {
  background: url("../images/BGPic.jpg") top center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 30em;
  padding-bottom: 30em;
  color: DodgerBlue;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 100px 50px;
  min-height: 5px;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 60px 50px;
}

.thumbnail {
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.thumbnail img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

video{
  width :100%;
  height:auto;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(70%);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-4 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 25px 0;
  }

  .btn-lg {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .logo {
    font-size: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60"> 
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">Slam Book </a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#about">About You</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blastFromPast">Blast From Past</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Sree">Special Friend</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Videos">Family and Friends</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#ATB">All The Best</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div  class="jumbotron text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h1><i><mark>Bla Bla Bla</mark></i></h1>
        <p><i><b><mark>Bla Bla Bla</mark></b></i></p>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div id="about" class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey">
    <h2><i>Bla Bla Bla</i></h2><br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="../images/IMG-20161114-WA0001.jpg"  width="400" height="300" >
        </div>
      </div>  
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h1>Bla Bla Bla</h1>
        <ol>
          <li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
          <li>Bla Bla Bla <h4><mark>Bla Bla Bla</mark></h4></li>
          <li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
          <li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
          <li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
          <li>Bla Bla Bla<mark>Bla Bla Bla</mark></li>
        </ol> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <br>
  <div id="blastFromPast" class="container"><br><br>
    <h1><i>Gallery....</i></h1>  
    <div id="myPhotos" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myPhotos" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myPhotos" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myPhotos" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li></li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Done!! Thanks in advance